# Why we should write "That"?

Tags: word-usage, relative-pronouns

> Global markets are waking up to an upbeat report on the U.S.- China
>   trade talks. Asian markets fell hard following the sell-off in the
>   U.S. yesterday, but a report out of Bloomberg News this morning
>   ***suggests the two sides are actually making progress*** despite the
>   inflamed rhetoric of late. That has U.S. futures set to open higher by
>   0.5% or more as of 7:00 am ET.

I feel the writer should have written ***that*** in the sentence "suggests the two sides are actually making progress, to be "suggests ***that*** the two sides are actually making progress." Sometimes I see "that" in such sentences, sometimes not. What is the rule here? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is that the complementiser *that* is completely optional in most contexts. (The exceptions mostly relate to relative clauses).

There is no difference in meaning, but sometimes it is clearer to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[..] a report out of Bloomberg News this morning suggests [that] the two sides are actually making progress despite the inflamed rhetoric of late.

that may be left out of the phrase given above.

the verb suggest can be followed by a noun phrase:

> The noun clause **usually** occupies the object position of the main
>   sentence: S + V + (that + S + V + O). Make sure you give your students examples where the main verb is in another tense such as the simple past—this way, they can clearly see the verb in the noun clause is a base verb and not another past verb. It is also helpful to include examples where the subject of the noun clause is in the third person singular so that students are really clear it's a base verb (and doesn't take an -s ending).
>
> Note: We can drop "that" from a noun clause, especially when speaking
>   quickly or in informal speaking and writing. **There is no change in
>   meaning** (i.e., *My friend recommended that we take a taxi home* and *My
>   friend recommended we take a taxi home* are identical in meaning).

[italics mine]

[recommend](https://esllibrary.com/blog/recommend)

I recommend reading the link carefully as it deals rather well with this issue for ELLers.

Comment: I think you've answered a different question than the one (that) OP was asking.

Comment: Lambie, thanks for your answer but do you mean if “that”  is a subject then we should write it. And in the above sentence it is not, so it is optional. Am I correct here?

Comment: @GamalThomas Yes, I misread the question. I will change my answer. Thankis.